# Is there a way to peek a value from a tty device

Tags: linux

Im writing a program which reads and writes to serial. I was wondering, is there a way to peek the next value from a tty device such as /dev/ttyS0 without removing it from the queue. I have looked for documentation or even source code for this module and have been so far, unable to find it. If anyone knows where it is, or which ioctls are available, please let me know.

Comment: Have you tried to see what happens?

Comment: I dont know what your asking. Ive looked for a way to peek the value and I cant find one.

Comment: How are you reading from the device?  If you show us what code you have, you might get some suggestions.  As it stands now we're completely in the dark.

Comment: Oh, it might also help if you told us *why* you want to do something like that.

Comment: Do you want to peek the value, or just know if there is something pending?

Comment: There is no posted source code because I havent written it yet. How I design the program will be dependant upon whether or not it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a combination of `getc` and `ungetc` will allow you to peek a single byte.

If you need more than one byte, you'll need to buffer it manually.

Comment: Are you sure that stdio streams should be used when accessing device nodes? As far as I know, mixing stdio calls with direct system calls (`ioctl`) is an invitation for *weird* things to happen...

Comment: stdio calls are fine to use in conjunction with ioctl; in fact, stdio will result in a syscall being run to do the actual I/O. It's a bad idea to combine stdio with C++ iostreams on the same file due to separation of buffers, but ioctl is fine.