# Read from serial port without removing from the buffer (linux)

Tags: c++, c, serial-port

In C/C++

How can I read from serial port, without removing the info I have already read from the buffer?

I want to do something like the Peek function of arduino (http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Peek) in a linux machine.

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900216/get-the-count-of-bytes-waitting-on-a-serial-port-before-reading-linux) can help.

Comment: Usually you would do this with your own buffer, not the one provided by the OS and used in kernel mode.

Comment: How are you reading from the serial port, now? A code snippet of the implemented buffer reading mechanism, could help you get more useful answers.

Comment: it is already answered here: [read from serail without remove](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478160/is-there-a-way-to-peek-a-value-from-a-tty-device)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The serial port is accessed as though it is a file using a file descriptor so a [fgetc ungetc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2082772/918124)  method should work.

Comment: Thank you! I also needed to use fdopen() in order to obtain a pointer to a FILE struct from the file descriptor (an integer).